# Selecting a DBMS

Tags: java, sqlite, database

I'm developing an application for data gathering from Internet and creating charts and plots from them with Java.
I need 2 tables (each about 50 columns) and each can have 2000 (maybe less but not more) rows of data in a day.
Currently I'm using SQLite but I doubt it be able to handle data for 6 month.
What DBMS you suggest me to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't have to worry about this. Any major DBMS should be able to handle that much data. Use whatever you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: So Can I continue with SQLite?

Comment: I would recommend using it until you hit a performance problem. When that happens, you can switch to any major non-lite DBMS. This should be fairly easy to do if you architect your application correctly. Don't hard code a dependency on any particular DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've got corporate reasons to choose otherwise, MySQL will do the job for you. 2000 rows a day won't tax it in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any DBMS of your choice, all supports and can handle large amount of data. You do not have to worry about this, any DBMS is tailored and built to handle such task effectively, and efficiently.